# If and elif question: which one is valid?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this two scripts with same content, but different if statements inside the loop:
Based on my understanding and `if, if` tests both conditions while `if, elif` testes up to the first condition that is `True` and ignores the next ones.

Why my instructor tells me that `if, elif` is the right answer? shouldn't both of them be valid answers?

```
def has_letter_cases(s: str) -> bool:
  """Return True if and only if s contains at least one lowercase letter 
  and an uppercase letter

  >>>has_letter_cases('abcABC')
  True
  >>>has_letter_cases('abc123')
  False
  >>>has_letter_cases('ABCXYZ')
  False
  """

  upper = False
  lower = False

  for ch in s:
    if ch.islower():
      lower = True
    if ch.isupper():
      upper = True

  return bool(upper and lower)
```

---

```
def has_letter_cases(s: str) -> bool:
  """Return True if and only if s contains at least one lowercase letter 
  and an uppercase letter

  >>>has_letter_cases('abcABC')
  True
  >>>has_letter_cases('abc123')
  False
  >>>has_letter_cases('ABCXYZ')
  False
  """

  upper = False
  lower = False

  for ch in s:
    if ch.islower():
      lower = True
    elif ch.isupper():
      upper = True

  return bool(upper and lower)
```

Comment: Both will produce the *same* result here, since a character can not be both uppercase and lowercase, the `elif` will be a bit more efficient since if the character is lowercase, you omit an extra check.

Comment: The reason for the second piece of code is that a single letter can either be a lower or an upper case, but not both at the same time. So imagine you are stepping through a `for` loop over the word "Hello", as you step over the 'H' `isupper()` will return `True` while `islower()` will return `False`, the same can be said for the rest of "Hello", where only one condition will return `True` at each iteration of the loop. however you are correct in your initial understanding of 2 `if` statements vs `if` and `elif`.

Comment: Something to add about the `if` `if` vs `if` `elif` is that in `if` `if` each condition could very well be totally different. For example `if myAge < 18` and `if myGender == 'Male'` notice how they are completely separate thoughts. While generally `if` `elif` follow the same logic. For example `if myAge > 18` and `elif myAge > 30`, notice how here the 2 conditions sort of follow the same thought process.